# Cannot send Slack notification via Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to send a Slack notification via Ansible:

```
- name: Send a custom slack notification
  run_once: true
  slack:
    #s3_backups Slack channel
    token: token/stuff/here
    attachments:
      - text: "S3 Web Server Config Backup Complete."
        title: S3 Web Server Backups
        color: "#8FCC2C"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

However, I'm getting a fatal error:

```
TASK [s3_fsn_backend_config_backup : Send a custom slack notification] ********************************************************************************************************************************************
Sorry, try again.
Sorry, try again.
fatal: [webserver-name -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "[sudo via ansible, key=blahblahblahblahblah] password:[sudo via ansible, key=blahblahblahblahblah] password:sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

Am I using incorrect syntax? I just want it to run from localhost. I definitely don't understand what the `Sorry, try again` message means.

Comment: It appears you have set `become: true` for your playbook but the `delegate_to: localhost` is also trying to `sudo` and is not configured to allow password-less sudo (nor should it, for using `slack:`). The `Sorry, try again.` is coming from the sudo prompt, as is the `sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts`

Comment: @mdaniel I removed the `become: true` and `become_method: sudo` and it gave me "Sorry, try again" again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code snippet

```yaml
- name: Send slack notifications
  slack:
    token: "{{ slack_token }}"
    msg: "Hello World"
    channel: "#general"
    username: "Ansible"
    icon_url: "https://www.ansible.com/favicon.ico"
    link_names: 1
    parse: "full"
    color: "#00ff00"
    attachments:
      - text: "This is an attachment"
        color: "#ff0000"
        fields:
          - title: "Field 1"
            value: "This is an attachment"
            short: false
          - title: "Field 2"
            value: "This is an attachment"
            short: false
        footer: "Footer"
        footer_icon: "https://www.ansible.com/favicon.ico"
        ts: 123456789
```

More details available at [slack_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/slack_module.html)

Comment: How do I know which username to use?

Comment: I edited the answer. You can refer the official module docs. Username is `This is the sender of the message.` and default is `Ansible`

Comment: I used "Ansible" and it failed. I can do curl requests to send messages to that channel. I can create a playbook with nothing but the Slack message (no user, just the token) and it sends. I still don't understand what's going on.

Comment: I removed `delegate_to: localhost` and kept `run_once: true` and it works now.